# jQuery Siblings tag "a"

Tags: jquery, siblings

Looks like simple but I cant find why it is not working. I am only trying to "removeClass" of the siblings of the rest siblings "a" tags when I click one of them. What I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

CSS ------->

```
.navigation li a{
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #544539;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

a.selected {
    background: #003662;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

HTML------->

```
<nav class="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" title="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="collect">Collect</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="spend">Spend</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="about">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

jQuery ------->

```
$(".navigation a").on("click", function() {                              
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("selected");
});
```

Comment: The given answers are correct, but to explain why. You are targeting the `a` element, which has no siblings, it's parent, the `li`, does have siblings, which in turn have a child element, the `a` you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. I thought I wasn't see it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
$(this).parent().siblings().find('a').removeClass("selected");//remove class from sibling a tags
$(this).addClass("selected");//and then add class to current a tag
```

you can also use:

```
 $('.selected').removeClass("selected");
 $(this).addClass("selected");
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to remove class `active` from all anchors and add it to current clicked anchor:

```
$(".navigation a").on("click", function() {                              
    $('.navigation a').removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n4dqr/)**

Answer (score 1):

do this in your JS

```
$(".navigation a").on("click", function() {                              
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("selected");
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mahavir4dev/v9LGY/

Answer (score 0):

Try simple way:

http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/fWKsV/

Change css to:

```
li.selected a {
    background: #003662;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(".navigation a").on("click", function() {                              
    var $li = $(this).closest('li');
    $li.addClass('selected')
    $li.siblings().removeClass("selected");
});
```